# How can I set Emacs tab settings by file type?

Tags: emacs

I need to be able to set the tab settings for the following file types:

- .rb: 2 soft spaces
- .css, .html.erb: 4 space tabs

I have tried the following, but none of it seems to alter my default tab settings for each of the file types.

```
;; js-mode-hook has also been tried
(add-hook 'javascript-mode-hook 
      '(lambda() 
        (setq tab-width 4)))

(add-hook 'css-mode-hook 
      '(lambda() 
        (setq tab-width 4)))

(add-hook 'html-mode-hook 
      '(lambda() 
        (setq tab-width 8)))
```

I am pretty new to emacs so my knowledge of configuration is pretty low.

Comment: you were asking for .rb files which are ruby files. But your hooks are for javascript. Also what is .erb?

Comment: I should've mentioned my current settings use 2 soft spaced tabs by default which works for the ruby files.  As for .erb files they are essentially html files with embedded ruby code. Checkout http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ERuby#erb for more info.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In emacs each mode has it's own indentation style. The main command to indent (bound to <kbd>TAB</kbd>) is `indent-for-tab-command`.
This command calls mode specific indentation function found in the variable `indent-line-function`. So each mode has it's own way of doing it.

For Ruby (for my emacs 2 is a default):

```
 (setq ruby-indent-level 2)
```

For CSS (again, default is 4 for me):

```
 (setq css-indent-offset 4)
```

Unfortunately SGML mode (on which HTML mode is based) has a very simple indentation mechanism and apparently the level is not configurable.
See the source code of `sgml-calculate-indent` function.

I personally find it weird. I am not writing HTML, but you can try to modify the `sgml-calculate-indent` function yourself :). Learn some lisp.

I am using js2 mode, and it indents perfectly by default. For js you have to search for js-indent-level or something similar.

Cheers.

Comment: With that I get the proper tab widths, but I still get soft tabs.  I tried (setq indent-tabs-mode t), but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: indent-tabs-mode is a buffer local variable. If you want to enable it globably use (set-default 'indent-tabs-mode t). This works for me for text mode at least. Some other modes may no take it into account. For instance ruby has `ruby-indent-tabs-mode` which will solve your problem for ruby. In css I have seen no effect so far, and can not find the variable responssable for that. Sorry. Apparently each mode's designer makes his own decision vis-a-vis the tabs functionality.

Comment: I have played with all the xxx-indent-tabs-mode that I could think of, but they are still all soft.

Comment: After coming back to emacs after having to work with textmate this week a lot of the tabs now work, except for css which give me 3 spaced soft tabs.

Comment: I have a feeling that javascript was not set as the current mode when this wouldn't work since it works fine now.

Comment: Maybe this has got to do with the version of Emacs, but my 23.2 has `css-indent-level` not `css-indent-offset`.

Comment: @VitoshKa how can we find the name of the variable to set for the given mode? For example, in your example above for CSS, you used css-indent-offset variable. I am looking for the variable to allow me to do the same thing for my R programs in Emacs. Is there a way to find the name of the specific variable to set for each mode?

Answer (score 7):

Theres a number of aspects to how Emacs does indentation. Setting the tab-width only specifics how big a tab is if a literal tab is inserted. If you don't wish to use literal tabs for indentation, then you should first disable their insertion [(from the manual
)](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Just-Spaces.html#Just-Spaces):

> Emacs normally uses both tabs and
>   spaces to indent lines. If you prefer,
>   all indentation can be made from
>   spaces only. To request this, set
>   indent-tabs-mode to nil. This is a
>   per-buffer variable, so altering the
>   variable affects only the current
>   buffer, but there is a default value
>   which you can change as well.which you can change as well.

However, to specify the indentation levels, you'll also need to set the [c-basic-offset value](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Customizing-Indentation.html) variable as well:

```
(add-hook 'html-mode-hook 
      '(lambda() 
        (setq c-basic-offset 4)
        (setq indent-tabs-mode nil))
```

In your case, you may only need the c-basic-offset but try a few combinations and see what works best.

Comment: I using the c-basic-offset I tried with and without the indent-tabs-mode as well as with/without tab-width and none of them worked.  I am using the emacs starter kit so is it possible that some other .el file is overriding my setting in chris.el?

Comment: After removing all the other config files except my custom file with only the setting you have above, I still get an indentation of 2 spaces on tabbing.

Comment: I believe VitoshKa's answer is more relevant in this case - what I describe should work for any cc-mode derived mode (e.g. java-mode, csharp-mode, etc.). Sorry if that's been misleading - my apologies.

Answer (score 6):

js-mode uses `js-indent-level` so put `(setq js-indent-level 4)` into your ~/.emacs (shouldn't have to be in a hook, even, but if you're wondering, it's js-mode-hook, not javascript-mode-hook).

If setting tab-width doesn't change your indentation level for a certain mode, it's often simplest to just open the source for that mode. I found this variable by doing `C-h f js-mode`, clicking the link "js.el", then searching for "indent", second hit from the top.

---

However, if you collaborate a lot with other people, it's often better to put a cookie at the top of the file. I typically do `// -*- tab-width: 8 -*-` in the file, and then I have stuff like this in my ~/.emacs:

```
(defvaralias 'c-basic-offset 'tab-width)
(defvaralias 'cperl-indent-level 'tab-width)
(defvaralias 'perl-indent-level 'tab-width)
(defvaralias 'js-indent-level 'tab-width)
```

so that I have less variables to deal with (and don't have to get warnings about the file-local variable being unsafe or whatever if the mode-writer forgot to declare it as safe)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ELPA's css-mode.el with emacs 23.1.1, you can parametrize the global setting for tab width for CSS files for the tab width by doing the following:
1) Type M-x customize-variable , 
2) Then type css-indent-level, 
3) Then after you change the variable to your liking, you do "Save for future sessions".

Answer (score 0):

For HTML and erb: if you are using `web-mode` (the mode provided by Spacemacs) it can be as simple as:

`(setq-default
   web-mode-code-indent-offset 2
   web-mode-markup-indent-offset 2)`

where `markup-indent-offset` refers to the actual tags and `code-indent-offset` refers to embedded Ruby in ERB, etc.